# Authorize.net having issues connecting

Tags: php, authorize.net

After downloading the php sdk using composer and creating the neccessary thing, and while trying to run the script so as to connect to the server, I run into this problem

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   JMS\Serializer\JsonDeserializationVisitor::startVisitingObject(JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata
>   $metadata, JMS\Serializer\object $object, array $type): void must be
>   compatible with
>   JMS\Serializer\Visitor\DeserializationVisitorInterface::startVisitingObject(JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata
>   $metadata, JMS\Serializer\Visitor\object $data, array $type): void in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Project/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JsonDeserializationVisitor.php
>   on line 14

And this the script I created(Using there example)

```
/* Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
       retrieved from the constants file */
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);

    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();

    // Create the payment data for a credit card
    $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
    $creditCard->setCardNumber("4111111111111111");
    $creditCard->setExpirationDate("2038-12");
    $creditCard->setCardCode("123");

    // Add the payment data to a paymentType object
    $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
    $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

    // Create order information
    $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
    $order->setInvoiceNumber("10101");
    $order->setDescription("Golf Shirts");

    // Set the customer's Bill To address
    $customerAddress = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
    $customerAddress->setFirstName("Ellen");
    $customerAddress->setLastName("Johnson");
    $customerAddress->setCompany("Souveniropolis");
    $customerAddress->setAddress("14 Main Street");
    $customerAddress->setCity("Pecan Springs");
    $customerAddress->setState("TX");
    $customerAddress->setZip("44628");
    $customerAddress->setCountry("USA");

    // Set the customer's identifying information
    $customerData = new AnetAPI\CustomerDataType();
    $customerData->setType("individual");
    $customerData->setId("99999456654");
    $customerData->setEmail("EllenJohnson@example.com");

    // Add values for transaction settings
    $duplicateWindowSetting = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
    $duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingName("duplicateWindow");
    $duplicateWindowSetting->setSettingValue("60");

    // Add some merchant defined fields. These fields won't be stored with the transaction,
    // but will be echoed back in the response.
    $merchantDefinedField1 = new AnetAPI\UserFieldType();
    $merchantDefinedField1->setName("customerLoyaltyNum");
    $merchantDefinedField1->setValue("1128836273");

    $merchantDefinedField2 = new AnetAPI\UserFieldType();
    $merchantDefinedField2->setName("favoriteColor");
    $merchantDefinedField2->setValue("blue");

    // Create a TransactionRequestType object and add the previous objects to it
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authOnlyTransaction"); 
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($amount);
    $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);
    $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
    $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($customerAddress);
    $transactionRequestType->setCustomer($customerData);
    $transactionRequestType->addToTransactionSettings($duplicateWindowSetting);
    $transactionRequestType->addToUserFields($merchantDefinedField1);
    $transactionRequestType->addToUserFields($merchantDefinedField2);

    // Assemble the complete transaction request
    $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId($refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

    // Create the controller and get the response
    $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
```

How can I solve the issue

Comment: This is a PHP version issue. What version of PHP are you running? Although the code written by Authnet is PHP 5.6 compatible it apparently has a dependency on a library that requires 7.2+/

Comment: I can't really say because am using vagrant(which is Homestead Improved owned by laravel creator)

Comment: Can you use `phpinfo()` in some script or by editing a file in your application?

Comment: I am using Php version 7.3 only But I still get this bug. What should I do?